# How does the index.html and firebase hosting work for react native project?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-hosting, react-native-web

I'm using Visual Studio with React Native to build a web application. I'm new this and I would like to host my project called (lost) as a web app using firebase hosting. Here is the project structure: [image]

Currently, the "backend" folder is empty but this is where I want to init firebase. I tried to do this but ended up with a launched web app showing a firebase welcome screen. This is because of the index.html generated when doing init firebase. The index.html file looks like this: [image]

**Is it possible to have the firebase related files in the "backend" folder? Am I supposed to change anything in the index.html file to make it show my project and not the welcome screen or is it supposed to be generated automatically somehow?**

Thank you! /William

Comment: I think you'd want to replace the index.html with your front-end code and store your front-code there. Your backend would be any server side code that would most likely exist as firebase functions rather than the hosting side as outlined here https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/use-cases - It looks like you basically need to swap your folders around and use backend for firebase functions

Comment: @TommyBs Okay, thank you so much! When I have moved the firebase hosting files to the frontend folder, how do I replace the Index.html with my own front-end code? I have an index.js file; is this somehow related?